# how to delete columns from data warehouse which are not referenced by views or stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have a data warehouse with many tables and some columns in these tables are referenced by views or stored procedures. 
I need to delete all the columns from data warehouse tables which are not referenced by either views or stored procedures.
One way is to use 'TEXT' field in SYSCOMMENTS like the code below which is something I found in stack overflow itself

```
set nocount on 
declare @Keyword as varchar(200)
set @Keyword = 'dimcustomerID'

SELECT DISTINCT
name, 
CASE o.xtype 
    WHEN 'S' THEN 'System Stored Proc'
    WHEN 'F' THEN 'Foreign Key'
    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table'
    WHEN 'V' THEN 'View'
    WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored Proc'
    WHEN 'PK' THEN 'Primary Key'
    WHEN 'TR' THEN 'Trigger'
    WHEN 'UQ' THEN 'Unique Index'
    WHEN 'D' THEN 'Default'
    WHEN 'FN' THEN 'User Defined Function'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END, 
text 
FROM
sysobjects o left join syscomments c ON c.id = o.id
WHERE
text LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' 
OR  name LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

but it fails when we have used * instead of column_name in our views or sp code

Do we have any other method to do this? I want to get rid of all the unnecessary columns and save space in my warehouse

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it fails when you have SELECT *. But this will still work after you delete a column from the underlying table, so why do you care that it fails?

Comment: First of all I think you should first modify all queries that are using SELECT * to only those columns you need in a specific case. Otherwise deleting columns could produce errors.

Comment: No, there is no other way.   This is an example of how, when you use "SELECT * ", you inevitably pay the price.

Comment: I can not delete a column if it is being used in a view or sp. That is why select * fails.